# Display pandas dataframe with larger font in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, pandas-styles

I have a small-shaped (5 rows, 3 columns) dataframe which I can display by calling `df` in jupyter cell. I would like to enlarge (font size) this output for presentation purpose. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play around with styles using [`df.style.set_table_styles()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

This might help:

```
heading_properties = [('font-size', '18px')]

cell_properties = [('font-size', '16px')]

dfstyle = [dict(selector="th", props=heading_properties),\
 dict(selector="td", props=cell_properties)]

df.style.set_table_styles(dfstyle)
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks! :)

Comment: it should be noted that `dict(selector="th", props=heading_properties)` is the same as `{"selector": "th", "props": heading_properties}`, and that the backslash at the end of the line is not needed when inside square brackets (or braces or parentheses).

Answer (score 7):

In order to change the default HTML style for all dataframes in a notebook and not having to apply the style individually to each dataframe, you have two options:

1. **For a single notebook** use the magic function `%%html`:

   In the first cell of your notebook put

   ```html
   %%html
   <style>
   /* Any CSS style can go in here. */
   .dataframe th {
       font-size: 18px;
   }
   .dataframe td {
       font-size: 16px;
   }
   </style>
   ```
2. **For all notebooks** adjust the Jupyter CSS style:

   Add the CSS style information

   ```css
   .dataframe th {
       font-size: 18px;
   }
   .dataframe td {
       font-size: 16px;
   }
   ```

   to one of the following files:

   - **Jupyter Notebook**:

     *$HOME/.jupyter/custom/custom.css*
   - **JupyterLab** (depending on the theme):

     *$HOME/anaconda3/envs/[ENVIRONMENT NAME]/share/jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css*

     or

     *$HOME/anaconda3/envs/[ENVIRONMENT NAME]/share/jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-light-extension/index.css*

     For the JupyterLab the custom.css is unfortunateley not used, so I do not see another way to change the CSS.

Comment: the above code (1) works well but the issue is that the table's index font size seems unaffected. Is there a workaround for setting the index size the same as cell size?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use this code in one line:

```
df.style.set_table_attributes('style="font-size: 17px"')
```